# Can/how would you do a publish/subscribe real time mobile app with Ionic 3 and Java server side?

Tags: java, tomcat, real-time, publish-subscribe, ionic3

Is it feasible to have Ionic 3 react to server-side events fired from a Tomcat App, to update a model in real time. And make sure events fired from server are received in the order sent.
At it's simplest, if the server sent a notification with a random number that the Ionic App could refresh as it receives notifications. And maybe some sort of sequence number in the payload that the client also keeps track of.
If so, could someone post an example. Thanks.
Also, if the client misses notifications, you'd probably have to re-pull the whole model, what techniques would people normally keep the app up to date, accurate, robust, and responsive.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this??

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up just using RESTFUL web services for my first attempt. Then let users do pull to refresh.